# PHP Многомерный массив. Как отсортировать в начале 1 часть, затем вторую и затем их объединить в одно целое

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Имеется задачка, для которой нужно решение. У меня есть многомерный массив:

```
["order_1"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "lkmndf"
    ["desc"]=>
    string(10) "lnkdlfnslk"
    ["files"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) "sort-logo.png"
      [1]=>
      string(60) "Lalaala.jpg"
    }
  }
  ["order_2"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "lkmnsldnkmflknsldkn"
    ["desc"]=>
    string(15) "lkndslfknlskdmn"
    ["files"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(12) "IMG_0.JPG"
      [1]=>
      string(63) "sort.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

В нем имеется ключ "files" который в начале надо объединить в строку через "," в "order_1" затем в "order_2" и затем объединить их в одно через пробел. И самая большая загвоздка в что этих "order" можно создавать до бесконечности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, то как то так (i - это ваши order_1, order_2...):

```
$arr = [
           "order_1"=>[
           "name"=>"lkmndf",
           "desc"=> "lnkdlfnslk",
           "files"=> ["sort-logo.png","Lalaala.jpg"]
        ],
          "order_2" =>[
          "name"=>"lkmnsldnkmflknsldkn",
          "desc"=>"lkndslfknlskdmn",
          "files"=> ["IMG_0.JPG", "sort.jpg"]
        ]
   ];
    $result = "";
    foreach($arr as $key => $value ) {
        $result .=  implode(',',$value['files']). " ";

    }
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: не совсем верно составлен код, т.к. при выполнении кода результат будет удвоенный при первом исполнении кода 2 раза выведется первая часть массива затем 2 раза вторая часть и в середине как раз получается тот самый нужный ответ

Comment: "sort-logo.png,Lalaala.jpg IMG_0.JPG,sort.jpg такой ключ нужен? Или Lalaala.jpg IMG_0.JPG ?

Comment: Должно получиться именно так : sort-logo.png,Lalaala.jpg IMG_0.JPG,sort.jpg

Comment: я заменил на рабочий код. Посмотрите, у меня так и возвращает.

Comment: да все верно спасибо!